# Unsupported operand type but it is defined and reports fine

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong but just can't figure it out.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

The functions are getting the place where the header is but says that I'm not getting anything when reporting.

```
def findheader(header):
    with open('Config.txt', 'r') as f:
        f = f.read()
        lines = f.split("\n")

    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if header in line: 
            index = I
            return index


def getword(header):
    index = findheader(header)
    with open('Config.txt', 'r') as f:
        f = f.read()
        lines = f.split("\n")

     newindex = index + 1
    word = lines[newindex]

    return word

with open('Config.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.seek(findheader('firsttime:') + 1)
        f.replace('True', 'False', 1)
```

Comment: Can you include the full traceback? Where's the exception being raised?

Comment: `findheader` might return `None`, which makes `index` equal to `None` and *not* something you can add 1 to. (The call to `seek` is also a candidate for the same error.)

Comment: Unrelated: `f` probably doesn't have a `replace` method, as it's not a string.

Comment: In function findheader index should be equal to i and not I

Comment: The call to `seek` is the more likely candidate, since `getword` isn't called at all in the code shown, but I noticed the problem with `getword` first.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help this is very useful!